# Json retornando dados errados - Android

Tags: android, json

Tenho uma activity que exibe os dados de um json vindo de uma url.
Os dados são exibidos, mas preciso mudar o conteúdo desse json de vez em quando(a url não muda).
O problema é quando mudo os dados no json ele não atualiza no app de primeira, eu tenho que fechar e abrir o app, aí sim, mostra o json atualizado. Então aparece o segundo problema, ao fechar a activity e abrir ela de novo, os dados exibidos são os de antes de atualizar o json.

Ex.: json1. Exibido; Atualizei pra json2. Tem que reiniciar o app pra mostrar atualizado no app. Exibido: json2. 
Fechou a activity, abriu de novo, exibe o json1, mesmo que na url estiver o json2.

O Código:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //outros códigos
    new JsonTask().execute("http://pastebin.com/raw/u5hFAx4N");
```

Pra recuperar o json:

```
 private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);
            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
        super.onPostExecute(resultado);

        String titulo = "";
        String imagem = "";
        String texto = "";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultado);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("item");

            JSONObject jsonArrayJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            titulo = jsonArrayJSONObject.getString("titulo");
            imagem = jsonArrayJSONObject.getString("imagem");
            texto = jsonArrayJSONObject.getString("texto");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        txtTitulo.setText(titulo);
        txtTexto.setText(texto);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(imagem)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .error(R.drawable.erro)
                .into(imgImagem);

    }
}
```

Ficou meio confuso mas acho que deu pra entender o que tá acontecendo.
Como resolver?